# Kitchen safe touchscreen recipe reader

Tags: equipment

I think it would be nice for me to have a rugged computer based networkable device with a touch screen mounted in the kitchen to bring up those difficult recipes.

Does anyone here have any experience with such equipment and so point me to a reliable one?

Comment: I would be concerned about grime on the screen from all that touching while cooking.  Also, touch screens are often a sanitation issue already.  This doesn't seem like the greatest idea, but I can see the appeal.

Comment: I was considering this and instead of a touchscreen you could always use a keyboard with a keyboard protector. That way with grime you can clean/replace the protector.

Comment: you usually know what you want to cook before you start cooking so it is not hard to imagine that one could call up a recipe on screen and then use that without touching afterwards when your fingers may be messy. There are industrial grade touch screens for factories and other hazardous places so I see no reason why a display along those lines would not be available for the kitchen, like anything else it would have to be maintained, It could be splash resistant so that it could be cleaned and sanitized, just like cutting boards.

Comment: I'd have to respectfully disagree about pulling it up beforehand and then not touching it.  There's a few things in my kitchen wrong with that (I've tried :) - first, the recipe is often too long for a screen and needs to be scrolled.  Second, sometimes I'm using modified versions of more than one recipe and combining them, or cooking more than one thing at a time.  Also, I listen to music or podcasts and often need to pause or press next.  I do like the industrial/restaurant supply cover route, that might work real well with a custom system instead of a tablet.

Comment: I am not asking for a small display tablet device, With some recipes you may need to scroll but a vast amount of my recipes hold on an a4 sheet that will display on a 15 inch portrait screen without the need for scrolling, the other thing to consider is this, sometimes you do not need to see all of the recipe at once, sometimes I need only to be reminded of a few things to do so I usually go to that spot, then there could be a number of styli anchored nearby for scrolling, there is also the possibility of an assistant, 99% of the time I have one and lastly, god forbid voice command :)

Comment: Grime: I pretend I have raw chicken on my hand before I touch my screen. (Meaning I wash and dry my hand well before changing anything). If I need to do any scrolling, or quick stuff. I use a chopstick. So far my 23" touchscreen has stayed fairly clean. I also listen to podcasts, watch videos, and whatever on the screen. If you're still paranoid, there are a number of industrial and or ruggedized monitors that are designed for harsh environments. They are just considerably more expensive.

Comment: Ah, yeah I was picturing a tablet sized screen, if you have a real monitor or larger touch screen device I could see how scrolling wouldn't be an issue.  Also, multiple, washable styli nearby is a great idea I hadn't considered!

Comment: @Simmerdown print them out and discard after use. The cost, power, and cleaning risk of a touch screen monitor can't be worth it. A page or two printed out each day is only a few cents

Comment: A cheap 8" android tablet might be the way to fly. For under $50, you get 16GB or so and an SD card slot. The Slot will get you up to 128GB storage. That's a lot of books. Aldiko reader, Libre Office, wi-fi, bluetooth. Lots of software for recipes. Toss it in a baggy. Not much $ lost when it ends up in your blender: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KWqw5SpITg8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not "rugged" yet, as I need to put a protective layer on the screen and hide some of the pieces. I will probably build the parts directly into the kitchen when I remodel (hopefully happening soonish). I built myself one out of a laptop with a broken screen and Acer T230H monitor (23", touch screen). It's just running windows 7, and still needs some tweaking. Call it a work in progress, but it works great. My wife and I love it. The laptop was lying around and the monitor was quite affordable (about $350ish CAD).

Comment: This is the path I'm going down right now as well, though in the new year I'll be trying to involve a solution that includes an Android tablet of some kind so it's easier to mount in different areas of the kitchen.

Answer (score 6):

I've been using an iPad as others have suggested. Option 1 is to vecro it to a cabinet or the fridge etc. where it is not in danger of getting caught in a spill. You can navigate just fine with a nuckle or the back of your wrist if your hands are a mess.

Option 2 is put it in a gallon zipper bag. I recommend the 'storage' type over the freezer type as the plastic is thinner and won't interfere with the screen. If you are going to be using it for something with audio it won't sound good, but if you have something with airplay (I use a in the kitchen you can shift the audio over there, which is a good idea anyway as the volume level of an iPad really can't compete with kitchen noise.

I'm considering putting in a permanently mounted 50" LCD screen when I remodel. If so it will be connected to a computer in the basement under the kitchen, and have a touchscreen overlay added to it. The overlay uses light beam interruption and senses 'touch' without you really having to make contact with the screen. This is probably more than most people want to mess with though.

Comment: Four feet of spare counter space?!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I actually use my iPad.  But here is a great way to mount one.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vTSDPKktbUk

Answer (score 1):

Find any PDA or tablet you like that has a resistive touchscreen, then vacuum seal it inside a plastic baggie. For perfect sealing, get one that can charge inductively, so you don't have to put a hole in the bag for the power cord.

Comment: If you're gonna try this, make good and sure you're not cutting off air to the passive (or active!) cooling systems, or you'll just end up cooking your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Have you just considered the typical web apps on whatever smartphone you might happen to have?  For instance, Epicurious.com just came out with an iPad/iPhone app where you can view your "recipe box" recipes.  The screen size would be the biggest problem.

Or, just find a cheap desktop (with a WiFi card) or a laptop and you'll be able to browse whatever sites you want.  I think having a dedicated recipe-finding machine is a bit impractical unless you're constantly cooking... albeit a very cool idea :-)

Comment: There are many uses for a computing device in the kitchen :)

Answer (score 0):

I understand your request. I have always wanted this as well. What I did was buy a 21 inch all in one computer (touchscreen enabled). This stays in the kitchen and is used for recipes only. I may enjoy some music videos while things are cooking. It can be done! Do not listen to the negative responses. :-D[image]

Answer (score -1):

I saw a deal on one of these a few weeks ago and while my mouse was haning over the buy-now box i had a mental picture of my cook-books.  Mine are covered with grit, grime, and god knows what else. Before you think about going with this solution think about what currently holds your recipies and what kind of shape it's in. If yours look anything like mine then your new shiny touch screen could be ruined in a very short time.

Also, think about where you're going to put this. Too close to the stove and you have heat/ steam issues; too far away and it's pretty useless to have a scroll touch-screen if you can't reach it. Also, when I'm in the kitchen I alomost always have something in my hands, wooden spoon, sharp knife, apple, whatever; I'm sure I would stab, bludgeon, or otherwise mangle a touch screen very quickly.

Comment: I am not sure you would mangle an industrial grade touch screen that easily, while one would have to think where to put it in the kitchen this should not be hard, these things are designed for very harsh environments heat/steam will not be big issues. The problem I have with paper based books is exatly what you are saying they are in dreadful condition, they are the ones with the sanitization problems, not so easy to sanitize paper, and people never usually do. If you can open your refrigerator or oven door no reason why you could not grab a stylus and scroll your display.

Comment: And if holding a knife means you might accidentally stab a monitor, I think you shouldn't be touching knives....

Comment: your kitches must not be as chaotic as mine is.

Comment: My knives are excessively (obsessively?) sharp. I think of it as a loaded gun, I don't point them at anything that I don't intend on destroying (cutting, dicing)... ever. Knives go back on the rack when I'm not cutting. I also wash my hands if I need to move around on the monitor.